# Powershell - Importing XLSX to Active Directory

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory

Hello and thanks for having me on my first post.  I am having difficulty writing what seems to be a simple script but proving a lot harder.  HR simply updates an XLSX sheet (She prefers it to be in Excel) so I found the PS command that can grab and import it (import-excel) - and it takes each object and I can put it into a variable and view it like below with only those fields...  Ultimately what i'm trying to accomplish is to use just the "business email" and update the manager using the "Manager Electronic Address" field.

```
Pay Group Name             : 22Home
Employee Display Name      : Test, Chris
Business Email             : christest@gmail.com
Location                   : 22Home
Hire Date                  : 39482
Manager Name               : Chris Admin
Manager Electronic Address : *********@gmail.com
Employment Status Name     : Active
```

I am able to update the manager field easily using SAMAccountName but not the email field...
This script works if I manually copy SAMAccountNames to a CSV...

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$Users = Import-csv C:\Users\chris\Documents\scripts\SAMManagers.csv 
foreach ($User in $Users) 
 { 
 Set-ADUser $User.UsAMAccountName -Manager $User.MsAMAccountName 
 }
```

I am trying to automate everything from the XLSX and schedule it to run every week so that we can simply dump the XLSX file into a directory and have it update the manager field automatically.  The script below is a simple way of how I wanted to accomplish it but it is not working.

```
Import-Excel "C:\ADManagers\IT Active List.xlsx" | ForEach-Object {
    $mail = $_
    $User = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter (mail=$_."Business Email")
    $Manager = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter (mail=$_."Manager Electronic Address")

Set-ADUser $User -Manager $Manager
}
```

I really appreciate any help in advance and have a headache after a few hours on this...
Chris

Comment: Try saving the `Import-Excel` result into a variable like `$var =  Import-Excel "filepath"; $user = get-aduser -ldapfilter (mail=$var."Business Email")` etc and see if it changes anything

Comment: This is a very common thing to do, with tons of videos and blogs covering the topic. It does not matter if it is xl, or txt, etc, as long as you can read the file and extract the properties, you can use them to add/modify user ADDS stuff.

Comment: Thanks I tried that but getting a bunch of null errors

Comment: If you are saying, that is the way your XL file looks, then that is not a csv file with multiple columns. That is an XL file with 1 column. Import-Csv will bring in a file data as a table, not a list (well if you are reading a file with more than 5 properties, it will show as a list), and that is not what you are showing in your data sample. Your property names also have spaces, and to use them you must properly quoate the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment...

[use spreadsheet to import ad users](https://www.bing.com/search?q=use%20spreadsheet%20to%20import%20ad%20users&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=use%20spreadsheet%20to%20import%20ad%20users&sc=1-34&sk=&cvid=17D4204820A641039974F1412A03FFCD)

Example:
[Create New Active Directory Users with Excel and PowerShell](https://petri.com/create-new-active-directory-users-excel-powershell)

```
import-csv -path c:\temp\users.csv | foreach {

$givenName = $_.name.split()[0] 
$surname = $_.name.split()[1]

new-aduser -name $_.name -enabled $true –givenName $givenName –surname $surname -accountpassword (convertto-securestring $_.password -asplaintext -force) -changepasswordatlogon $true -samaccountname $_.samaccountname –userprincipalname ($_.samaccountname+”@ad.contoso.com”) -city $_.city -department $_.department
}
```

Yet, if you are saying the HR folks are just dumping the file, and you want a process to run the above script, then set a [FileSystemWatcher](https://www.bing.com/search?q=filesystemwacher&form=ANNTH1&refig=7937590eca2746cfb92a2222f906cafe&sp=-1&pq=filesystemwache&sc=8-15&qs=n&sk=&cvid=7937590eca2746cfb92a2222f906cafe) or a scheduled task to monitor the folder that will trigger the script execution.

Sample: 
[filesystemwacher PowerShell gallery](https://www.bing.com/search?q=filesystemwacher%20powershell%20gallery&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=filesystemwacher%20powershell%20gallery&sc=0-35&sk=&cvid=7EC10D301C1040C8A04B5823908786E0)
[Download: FileSystemWatcher.ps1](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b)

***Update***

When you read a file with properties that have spaces, you have to quote them.

In a normal use case, a properly formatted csv file would look like this.

```
"Pay Group Name","Employee Display Name","Business Email","Location","Hire Date","Manager Name","Manager Electronic Address","Employment Status Name"
"22Home","Test, Chris","christest@gmail.com","22Home","39482","Chris Admin","*********@gmail.com","Active"
```

... and when you read that file, you'd have to physically quote any property that has spaces or special characters.

```
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\SAMManagers.csv' | 
ConvertFrom-Csv | 
ForEach-Object {
    "Working on user: $($PSItem.'Business Email') and manager name: $($PSItem.'Manager Electronic Address')"
    # Set-ADUser -Identity $($PSItem.'Business Email') -Manager $($PSItem.'Manager Electronic Address') -WhatIf
}

# Results
<#
Working on user: christest@gmail.com and manager name: *********@gmail.com
#>
```

So, your target cmdlet use case would be something like this...

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
Import-csv -Path 'C:\Users\chris\Documents\scripts\SAMManagers.csv' | 
ForEach-Object {
    $SetADUserSplat = @{
        Identity = $PSItem.'Business Email' 
        Manager  = $PSItem.'Manager Name' 
        WhatIf   = $true # Remove this if you want this to really happen
    }
    Set-ADUser @SetADUserSplat
}
```

Comment: Thanks and I know how to create users from scratch using CSV's.  My problem is that I am limited on the information that is on the XLSX file.  I am trying to take that Excel sheet which only has emails of the user and managers.  I am get the script to go through each object, find the email in AD, assign it to a variable and then run the set-aduser command.  get-aduser -ldapfilter "(mail=christest@gmail.com)" works but I cannot seem to get that from each object.

Comment: This was really not about adding a user from scratch, but the same way you'd read a file to add new is the same way you'd use a file to update or delete. You are not showing how the xls is formed. If it is just a two-column file, then you use the column name as the properties. If you are saying it is not a formtted as a simple 2 column file, then you need to show how it's setup. If it does not have headers, then you can add thos eon the import as teh property names.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and I apologize if I read that wrong.  I am really grateful for your help.  The XLSX is pretty straight forward with just 8 columns as I posted in my original example.  My main problem is that I cannot seem to get a variable (specifically SAMACCOUNT NAME) from the input of 'mail' attribute and use that to update using set-aduser
Pay Group Name,Employee Display Name,Business Email,Location,Hire Date,Manager Name,Manager Electronic Address,Employment Status Name
22Home,"Test, Chris",christest@gmail.com,22Home,2/4/2008,Chris Admin,chris*****@gmail.com,Active

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to get this working...  I'm sure there are a lot more ways of doing this shorter, but this way works for me...  Import-Excel works really well but the problem was manipulating that email address attribute and converting it to SamAccountName.

Obviously you can read the code below but I wanted to explain why I did it this way...

1. Import-Excel Function grabs the Excel file and sets it to a variable $ADUser
2. Creates a TXT Files of the users email
3. Creates a TXT Files of the managers email
4. Converts Users email to SamAccountName property in AD into a csv
5. Converts Managers email to SamAccountName property in AD into a csv
6. Combine both CSV's into a single one with separate columns - TXT
7. Convert TXT to final CSV
8. Run the command that updates all manager attributes
9. Delete temporary files

-

```
    $ADUsers = Import-Excel "C:\ADManagers\IT Active List.xlsx"
    $ADUsers."Business Email" | out-file -filepath C:\ADManagers\users.txt
    $ADUsers."Manager Electronic Address" | out-file -filepath C:\ADManagers\managers.txt

    Get-Content "C:\ADManagers\users.txt" | ForEach-Object {
      $mail = $_
      $user = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(mail=$mail)"
      if ( $user ) {
        $sAMAccountName = $user.sAMAccountName
      }
      else {
        $sAMAccountName = $null
      }
      [PSCustomObject] @{
        "ADUser" = $sAMAccountName
      }
    } | Export-Csv "C:\ADManagers\User-Output.csv" -NoTypeInformation

    Get-Content "C:\ADManagers\managers.txt" | ForEach-Object {
      $mail = $_
      $user = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(mail=$mail)"
      if ( $user ) {
        $sAMAccountName = $user.sAMAccountName
      }
      else {
        $sAMAccountName = $null
      }
      [PSCustomObject] @{
        "Manager" = $sAMAccountName
      }
    } | Export-Csv "C:\ADManagers\Manager-Output.csv" -NoTypeInformation

    $file1 = Get-Content "C:\ADManagers\User-Output.csv"
    $file2 = Get-Content "C:\ADManagers\Manager-Output.csv"

    $content = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $file1.Length; $i++)
    {
        '{0},{1}' -f $file1[$i].Trim(), $file2[$i].Trim()
    } 
    $content | out-file "C:\ADManagers\Output.csv"
    import-csv -path "C:\ADManagers\Output.csv" | export-csv -path "C:\ADManagers\ADUsers.csv" -Delimiter "," -notypeinformation

    Remove-Item C:\ADManagers\users.txt
    Remove-Item C:\ADManagers\managers.txt
    Remove-Item C:\ADManagers\User-Output.csv
    Remove-Item C:\ADManagers\Manager-Output.csv
    Remove-Item C:\ADManagers\Output.csv

    $Users = Import-csv "C:\ADManagers\ADUsers.csv"
    foreach ($User in $Users) 
     { 
     Set-ADUser $User.ADUser -Manager $User.Manager
     }

Remove-Item C:\ADManagers\ADUsers.csv
```